# Read/Unread Emails in Outlook 2013 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: email, troubleshooting, microsoft-outlook-2013, windows-server-2012

We have an issue where we have users try and mark email messages in Outlook 2013 as unread/read but these changes do not take effect until you have closed outlook and re-opened it.

This issue is happening on 4 different Windows Server 2012 servers with different mail servers.

Comment: Not sur eI follow -- Are the users RDPing into the servers and using Outlook from there? Does this happen for ALL users or just some? Always the same users affected? Does it always behave like this for affected users, or is it intermittent?

Comment: Hi Techie007 thanks for the reply. Yes the RDPing into the server and using Outlook from there.

Comment: It does happen for all users - even our admin profile which has an admin@ outlook profile has the same issues. It is not intermittent it is happening all the time